# Getting a forwarding source number with amazon connect

Tags: amazon-connect

If I forward an incoming call to a cell phone to a number I got from amazon connect, can I determine the number from which the call is coming?

I know the source and the amazon connect phone number, but how should I get the source of the incoming call?

Comment: How forwarding is done?

Answer (score 0):

Within connect the `$.CustomerEndpoint.Address` attribute (Listed in Namespace: `System`, Value: `Customer number` when using a set contact attributes block) is the phone number of the incoming call that Connect receives.

What that number is set to is determined by the calling party. If when forwarding your mobile sets this to the transferring mobile's number, then there is no way for Connect to get the original number the call came from.

If you are transferring the call from Connect to another number then the calling number Connect sends is either based on the active queue for the call, or is set in the Transfer to phone Number block.

If you want to send the original number when transferring out, set the active queue to a queue where `Default caller ID name` and `Outbound caller ID Number` are blank.